# How call Async methods in Controller MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have used before SignalR and ASP.net MVC.

I have two buttons in MVC.net named respectively "Cancel" and "Save".

In the Controller where the "Save" button is, I have a "`ForEach`" and a "`ForEach`"

I have tried using `ProgressBar` in define in MainHub.

The `ForEach` is defined so that `ProgressBar` is incremented every iteration within the loop.

Question:

How to call `async` method on "Cancel" which can break out of "ForEach" on the controller where the "Save" button is?

The `Save` button invokes an AJAX JQuery once pressed.

Comment: Your problem is really unclear here. You definitly should provide the relevant Code instead of just putting some explanations, that would help a lot.

Comment: question : How can Async Two Action in controller MVC.net